# PHP: default function parameter value for a lambda

Tags: php, function, lambda, default

Is it possible for a PHP function which has a lambda parameter to have a default value?

While the following works fine:

```php
function calcValue($func) {
  echo $func(5);
}

calcValue(function($a){return 2*$a;});
```

when I try:

```php
function calcValue($func = function($a){return 2*$a;}) {
  echo $func(5);
}
```

I get a parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)
```

Answer (score 1):

A default value must be a constant expression. See this question for more details: [PHP Anonymous Function as Default Argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831679/php-anonymous-function-as-default-argument)

Answer (score 1):

Default values in function calls have to be constants. They cannot be a dynamic value/expression result.

```
good: function($foo = 'bar');
bad:  function($foo = bar());
bad:  function($foo = 'ba' . 'r'); // to PHP it's still an expression.
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: PHP 5.6 will support constant scalar expression (3rd variant) - see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs